# Remove the javascript object variable name text from json code

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have a String variable that stores the literal text of a JavaScript object:

```
String jsString = "mainData = {"name":"John", "id":"12345"}"
```

Is there a JSON method (or any method) in Java that will remove the "mainData = " part of the string in order to leave only the JavaScript data? Something like this:

```
newString = someMethod(jsString);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(newString); //newString = "{"name":"John", "id":"12345"}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`String#replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
jsString = jsString.replaceFirst("^[^{]+", "");
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Mzdrdu)

That will remove any characters as the start of the string prior to the first `{`. It makes the assumption that the string contains JSON where the outermost thing is an object (as opposed to an array or just a value), although it could readily be tweaked not to make that assumption. For instance, this version:

```
jsString = jsString.replaceFirst("^\\s*[A-Za-z0-9_$]+\\s*=\\s*", "");
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/XLmjgv)

That removes a series of letters, numbers, `_`, or `$`, optionally surrounded by whitespace, and a following `=`, possibly followed by whitespace, at the beginning of the string. Now, that's not a complete list of valid JavaScript identifier characters (that list is **long**), but you get the idea.

Comment: Cool, I've never used Regex before so this is good to know. Also, I could've easily made a simple method of my own that will remove any characters before the first '{' or '[' but I was just curious if some specific JSON method in Java already existed that did this. Thanks for the detailed answer!